# Handlebars helper: how do you run code after the template was rendered?

Tags: handlebars.js

I am writing an application using handlebars, but no Meteor or Ember.

I am writing a helper which needs to run some code after the html was rendered, in order to attach `onclick`s to some dom elements. Is there a way to do that in the helper, without relying on an ugly `setTimeout` or something similar?

I found the solution for Meteor-based applications, but not when only handlebars is used.

Template:

```
{{#autocomplete config}}{{/autocomplete}}
```

Helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('autocomplete', function(config) {
  return autocompleteTemplate();
});
```

Comment: Can you show how you are rendering handlebar template?

Comment: Is that the information you needed?

Comment: Yes, because it is the point after which  you can add your bindings.

Comment: Actually, you will find the javascript where it is rendering the generated html. Check this guild for more details http://handlebarsjs.com/#getting-started

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your comment. You mean I should add the javascript in my template? I'd really like to avoid that if I can.

Comment: Not really. I meant to find the code which is responsible for attaching compiled html (from handlebar template) to DOM. You can add your bindings right after that.

Comment: Search for `Handlebars.compile` and you will find the code nearby.

Comment: I don't want whoever is calling the autocomplete to have to handle attaching the events. It should be the responsibility of the helper, not of the view, or its controller.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything built in that would do this, so I ended up wrapping the Handlebars.compile in a helper function that could do post-processing to rendered templates.

```
function compileWithExtras(template, options) {
    var template = Handlebars.compile(template, options);
    return function() {
        var rendered = template.apply(null, arguments);
        //do your post processing here
        return rendered;
    };
}

var exampleTemplate = compileWithExtras(document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML);
var postProcessedHtml = exampleTemplate(data);
```

If you're precompiling templates then you will need to target `Handlebars.precompile` which will be a little trickier, though a simple `replace('return buffer;','return postProcess(buffer);')` may be all that's needed, e.g.,

```
    function postProcess(buffer) {
    //do your post processing here
    return buffer;        
}   

function precompileWithExtras(template, options) {
    return Handlebars.precompile(template, options)
        .replace('return buffer;','return postProcess(buffer);');
}
```